# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2 (2+\sin x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry

Self studying and would like some reassurance, all criticism/corrections are welcome.

We show $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2 (2+\sin x)} = 0$

First we note that $-1 \le \sin x \iff 1 \le 2 + \sin x \iff \frac{1}{2+\sin x} \le 1$ and $0 \le \sin^2 x \le 1$.

So we can write $\frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2 (2+\sin x)} \le \frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2} = \frac{\sin^2 x}{x} + \frac{2 \sin^2 x}{x^2} \le \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x^2}$ and
$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x^2} = 0$.

From the previous inequalities we can see $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2 (2+\sin x)}$ is nonnegative for $x > 0$. We have $2+x > 0$, $\sin^2(x) \ge 0 $ and $x^2 >0$ because they are squares, and $2 + \sin x \ge 1 > 0$ as shown above. Since these are all nonnegative, the main expression is nonnegative.

Therefore for large $x$, we have $ 0 \le \frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2 (2+\sin x)} \le (\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x^2})$ and by the squeeze theorem $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{(2+x)\sin^2 x}{x^2 (2+\sin x)} = 0$.

(from Velleman's *Calculus: A Rigorous First Course*)

Comment: Seems everything fine for me, I will just say that I don't agree with "From the previous inequalities we can cleary see" that the expression is nonnegative, since they aren't enough to show that. I'd quickly write why the expression is nonnegative when $x>0$ for example ($x> -2$ is enough but yeah). This is a minor thing tho.